# Unexpected Identifier jquery

Tags: javascript, identifier

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url:"url",
      cache: false,
      success: function(response){
         $('#investigationGrid').html(response);
      },
      error: function(){
        alert('Error while request..');
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: `$j` looks wrong to me

Comment: as the word `jquery` doesn't appear in the code you posted, can you actually ask a question, because the title means nothing, and the code - apart from what could be a simple typo when typing it out - looks cromulent

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo; remove the "j."

```
$(document)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$j(document)` with `$(document)`